# Divine Providence for individuals and purpose of Creation

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, creation, hashgacha-pratit

This question is about Jewish philosophers. I ask myself if there is not a logical link between two issues and it is, if authors address it

Is there a link between the theory that the world was created only for mankind (Rav Saadia Gaon, [Sefer Hayashar chapt. 14](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01593.html?dyn#HtmpReportNum0014_L2) (1)) and the theory that hashgacha pratit is for man alone (Rambam in More, Ramban, [Chinuch 169](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01644_part_169.html) (2), pratit versus klalit hashgacha)?

Another version of the question: is there a contradiction between the theory that all is created for mankind and the theory that there is hashgacha pratit for all things (Baal Shem Tov and disciples (3))?

If all is for man, what is the purpose of hashgacha for a tree leaf that nobody knows or an individual and isolated ant?

---

(1): יש לאדם להביט יצורי הבורא והשמים והארץ וכל צבאם, ולדעת כי לא נברא הכל כי אם בעבור האדם

(2): ולפי שהדעות רבות בהשגחת האל על כל ברואיו, יבואו בה הרבה פסוקים במקרא והרבה מצות להורות על הענין מהיותו פנה גדולה בתורתנו. שיש כתות בני אדם יחשבו כי השגחת השם יתברך [על כל המינין בפרט בין אנשים או כל שאר בעלי חיים, ויש מהן כתות יחשבו כי השגחת השם ברוך הוא] על כל עניני העולם בין בעלי חיים או כל שאר דברים, כלומר שלא יתנועע דבר אחד קטן בעולם הזה רק בחפצו ברוך הוא ובגזרתו עד שיחשבו כי בנפל עלה אחד מן האילן הוא גזר עליו שיפל, ואי אפשר שיתאחר או יקדם זמן נפילתה אפילו רגע, וזה דעת רחוק הרבה מן השכל. ויש כתות רעות יחשבו שלא ישים השגחתו ברוך הוא כלל בכל עניני העולם השפל, בין באנשים או בשאר בעלי חיים, והוא דעת הכופרים, רע ומר. ואנחנו בעלי הדעת האמיתים לפי מה ששמעתי נשים השגחתו ברוך הוא על כל מיני בעלי חיים בכלל, שכל מין מן המינים הנבראים בעולם, יתקיים לעולם, לא יכלה ויאבד כלו, כי בהשגחתו ימצא קיום לכל דבר. ובמין האדם נאמין כי השגחתו ברוך הוא על כל אחד ואחד בפרט, והוא המבין אל כל מעשיהם (תהלים לג טו). וכן קבלנו מגדולינו, וגם נמצא על זה הרבה כתובים יורו כי הענין כן

(3): Peri Haarets parshat Bo (may be that some sources are clearer, this one may be commented in different ways)  ואין שום עשב יבש ונעקר ואין שום אבן נזרק כי אם בזמן ומקום הראוי לו כמאמר אל מקום אשר יפול העץ שם יהוא ואין שום תנועה גדולה וקטנה מן הצמצום הראשון עד שפל המדרגות שבארץ ותחת לארץ הכל מאתו ית' כפי חכמתו בשמו ולכבודו לגלות אלהותו וחכמתו ומדתו ית' מה הוא חנון ורחום

Comment: improvement in wording, phrasing or syntaxe are welcome

Comment: Please provide links and precise citations to the specific Moreh Nevuchim, Ramban, and Sefer HaChinuch which say that Hashgacha Pratit only applies to men. Also a link to Sefer HaYashar of Saadia Gaon. It sounds like you may be mistranslating something.

Comment: There are many books called Sefer HaYashar. Are you referring to the midrash? And the citations you are mentioning here, including the new one from Chovot HaLevavot, are hundreds of pages long each. Do you have specific citations, meaning exact chapters, pages, 'beginning with the words, etc? I'm not criticizing your question. I know it's a pain, but without seeing the language of your sources in Hebrew, it's difficult to respond to your question. Like I mentioned, it sounds like you are understanding certain Hebrew word usage incorrectly.

Comment: And saying that "Sefer HaYashar is found after Torah Emet",  likewise could be many different places. You need to provide and clarify.